# Redshift - Finding number of times a flag appears for a particular ID

Tags: sql, count, amazon-redshift

I have some sales data that shows if a bill has been generated for a customer. The column labelled bill_generated returns 'Y' if a bill has been generated else its blank. I am trying to find the list of customers for whom atleast one bill has been generated. There could be multiple rows for each cust_id as shown below:

```
cust_id, bill_generated
001,NULL
001,Y
002,NULL
002,NULL
003,Y
```

Could anyone advice on this. I am using Redshift DB. Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use co-related sub-query

```
select * from t
           where exists (select 1 from t t1 
             where t1.bill_generated='Y' and t1.cust_id=t.cust_id
            )
```

Answer (score 2):

Try below using group by and having cluse

```
select cust_id from tablename
group by cust_id 
having sum(case when bill_generated is null then 0 else 1 end)=1
```

Comment: I think this is the best method.  But the `having` clause would be better written as `count(bill_generated) > 0`.